# Java 9 Behavior of Flow SubmissionPublisher offer method

Tags: java, java-9, reactive-streams, java-flow

I´ve been playing with Java Flow `offer` operator but after read the documentation and do my test I dont understand.

Here my test

```
@Test
public void offer() throws InterruptedException {
    //Create Publisher for expected items Strings
    SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();
    //Register Subscriber
    publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
    publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
    publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
    publisher.offer("item", (subscriber, value) -> false);
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

The offer operator receive an item to be emitted and a BiPredicate function, and as far as I understand reading the documentation, only in case that the predicate function is true the item it will be emitted.

Bur after pass the test the result is

```
Subscription done:
Subscription done:
Subscription done:
Got : item --> onNext() callback
Got : item --> onNext() callback
Got : item --> onNext() callback
```

There´s no change in the result if instead of false I return true.

Anybody can explain me this operator a little bit better please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, the predicate function is used to decide whether to *retry* the publishing operation as mentioned in the [docs](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html#offer-T-java.util.function.BiPredicate-):

> `onDrop` - if non-null, the handler invoked upon a drop to a subscriber, with arguments of the subscriber and item; if it returns true, an offer is re-attempted (once)

It does not affect whether or not the item is to be sent initially.

**EDIT: An example of how drops can occur when using the `offer` method**

I came up with an example of how drops could occur when calling the `offer` method. I don't think the output is 100% deterministic, but there is a clear difference when it is run several times. You can just change the handler to return true instead of false, to see how the retry reduces the drops due to saturated buffers. In this example, the drop would typically occur because the max buffer capacity is explicitly small (passed to the constructor of `SubmissionPublisher`). But when the retry is enabled after a small sleep period, the drops are removed:

```
public class SubmissionPubliserDropTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create Publisher for expected items Strings
        // Note the small buffer max capacity to be able to cause drops
        SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher =
                               new SubmissionPublisher<>(ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), 2);
        // Register Subscriber
        publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
        publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
        publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
        // publish 3 items for each subscriber
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int result = publisher.offer("item" + i, (subscriber, value) -> {
                // sleep for a small period before deciding whether to retry or not
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;  // you can switch to true to see that drops are reduced
            });
            // show the number of dropped items
            if(result < 0) {
                System.err.println("dropped: " + result);
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        publisher.close();
    }
}

class CustomSubscriber<T> implements Flow.Subscriber<T> {

    private Subscription sub;

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("onComplete");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
        sub.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T arg0) {
        System.out.println("Got : " + arg0 + " --> onNext() callback");
        sub.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription sub) {
        System.out.println("Subscription done");
        this.sub = sub;
        sub.request(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I might be dumb, but after modify my test and read again the doc still dont get it. Do you think you could elaborate a very simple example?. Dont worry if you cannot I will figure out.

Comment: As the documentation says "The item may be dropped by one or more subscribers" How can I reproduce that behave?. I was just trying in the first onNext and in the onSubscribe the first time, just make a subscription.cancel() but still dont see any changes in the result

Comment: @paul I'm also interested in such an example (trying it now). Will update the answer if I come up with it.

Comment: Thanks If I make it works I will let you know as well

Comment: Probably trying out specifying the [least value to the timeout to offer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502655/1746118) could work here.

Comment: @paul I think I came up with one example.

Comment: Great!! let´s take a look ;)

Comment: Very good example, thanks a lot, now it´s perfectly clear what this operator it´s about

Answer (score 3):

**[`SubmissionPublisher.offer`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html#offer-T-java.util.function.BiPredicate-)** states that

> The item may be dropped by one or more subscribers if resource limits
>   are exceeded, in which case the given handler (if non-null) is
>   invoked, and if it returns `true`, retried once.

Just to understand, in both of your calls

```
publisher.offer("item", (subscriber, value) -> true); // the handler would be invoked

publisher.offer("item", (subscriber, value) -> false); // the handler wouldn't be invoked
```

***But still the `publisher` publishes the given item, to each of its current subscriber.*** which happens in your current scenario.

---

The scenario to validate if the handler that you've provided is getting invoked or not by trying to reproduce is tough in terms of resource limitations, as the doc suggests:

> The item may be dropped by one or more subscribers *if resource limits
>   are exceeded*, in which case the given handler (if non-null) is
>   invoked, and if it returns true, retried once.

Yet you can try dropping the items with timeouts set to base minimum using 
the overloaded method for [`offer​(T item, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, BiPredicate<Flow.Subscriber<? super T>,? super T> onDrop)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html#offer-T-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-java.util.function.BiPredicate-)

> `timeout` - how long to wait for resources for any subscriber before
>   giving up, in units of unit
>
> `unit` - a TimeUnit determining how to
>   interpret the timeout parameter

Since the `offer` methods may drop items (either immediately or with ***bounded timeout***), which would provide an opportunity to interpose a handler and then retry.

Comment: Thanks for the info ;)